# Autoclick a button on a site in chrome

Tags: javascript, xpath, automation, automated-tests, automapper

I was searching for solution to autoclick a button on a website. I've read multiple sites and got to know to use Xpath of an element on the site. I've used an third party extension named "Laura Autoclicker" for chrome. The extension requires the target website and Xpath of the element. But the Xpath of the button keeps changing everytime the page loads.

```
<li>    
<a id="itVabq" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$itVabq','')">NEW
                                        BOOKING</a>
</li>
```

Above is the code I found while inspecting the button. The id keeps changing. 
Is there anyway to set up autoclick for that type of button?? 
Please help me.

Comment: Is there any pattern to the id's. I was thinking you could find the parent list and then filter the list elements for the one your want

Answer (score 0):

You need an xpath that is guaranteed to work. If the ID is dynamically generated, try using the element's `text()` or another property that is always the same like this:

```
'//a[text()="NEW BOOKING"]'
```

or maybe

```
'//li/a[text()="NEW BOOKING"]'
```